# how to remove previous frame's rectangle from canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to drawing a Rectangle in a canvas and rectangle co-ordinates I am getting from JSON file.

It was drawing successfully but It is not removing the previous rectangle.

I tried with context.beginPath(), context.clearRect() but none of them are working.

HTML code :

```
var canvasfabric = new fabric.Canvas('layer2');
  layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
  ctx1 = layer1.getContext("2d");
  layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
  ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");
  layer3 = document.getElementById("layer3");
  ctx3 = layer3.getContext("2d");

    function box(j,a){
                    ctx1.beginPath();
                    ctx1.font = "bold 15px Verdana";
                    ctx1.lineWidth = "5";
                    ctx1.strokeStyle = "red";
                    ctx1.fillstyle = "#6af547";
                    var k = a;

                    if (myVideo.paused == false){

                            if(k <= data[j].Total_objects_detected){
                                var x1 = data[j].output[k].x_val;
                                var y1 = data[j].output[k].y_val;
                                var width1 = data[j].output[k].width;
                                var height1 = data[j].output[k].height;

                                var rect = new fabric.Rect({width: width1, height: height1, fill: '#ffffff00', stroke: 'rgba(34,177,76,5)', strokeWidth: 5, top: y1, left: x1});
                                canvasfabric.add(rect);

                                ctx1.fillText(data[j].output[k].Objects_classname, x1 + 5, y1 - 10);
                                k++;

                            }    
                    }
                   ctx1.stroke();
                   ctx1.beginPath();
                }
```

Here j = frame-number , a = how many number of rectangle (0-10)

Let me know if you want any further part of code or any query.

Comment: you can use `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` to clear canvas for redrawing. or in fabric.js `canvas.clear();`

Comment: @ArvindDhakad let me try

Comment: @ArvindDhakad can you tell me at what part of code I need to write because I tried in replace of ctx1.beginPath() but it is not working and canvasfabric I am giving to layer2 so what should i write instead of canvas or context?

Comment: what you want to do here?

Comment: Here I'm drawing a bounding box and co-ordinates I am getting from JSON file...But the problem here is assume that frame number 1 has 3 object's bounding box data so it is drawing but once next frame comes means frame number 2, it has (frame number 1's data) remove from the canvas but that is not happening. All the frames data it's appending I means it's not delete previous state .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p390vkyg/1/ chk this fiddle for more info.