# how to retrieve text data in fabricjs?

Tags: html, fabricjs

I wanted to retrieve text data from the fabric text.

I tried with .get('text') but it's telling undefined.

This is my HTML code :

```
 function save(obj){                                         
canvasfabric.forEachObject(function(obj){
                         // var textname =  canvasfabric.setActiveObject().setText(event.target.value);
                          // alert(textnew);
                           //var text = canvasfabric.getActiveObject();
                          // alert(text.get('type'));
                          //canvasfabric.setActiveObject(textnew);

                          //var text = obj.get('type');
                         // var text1 = obj.get('text');
                        alert("frame : "  + i  + "\n" 
                               +      "x : " + obj.left   + "\n"
                               +      "y : " + obj.top    + "\n" 
                               +  "width : " + obj.width  + "\n" 
                               + "height : " + obj.height + "\n" 
                               +  "class : " + obj.get('text')); 
                        });
                        //alert("Data has been saved Successfully");
                    }
```

Anybody here can help me to retrieve objects text data.

Comment: Which fabric.js version are you using?

Comment: use `obj.text` to get text value

Comment: @Durga I tried but it is giving undefined.

Comment: then may be the object you are getting is not a type of text object

Comment: @shkaper I am using 2.3.5 Version.

Comment: @Durga yes!! that's what I need. How to get the text of object.

Comment: [canvasfabric.getObjects('text')](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getObjects) to get all text objects

Comment: @Durga I tried with canvasfabric.getObjects('text') but it is giving me blank space.

Comment: create a snippet/fiddle stating the issue

Comment: chk https://jsfiddle.net/13puats6/  if you want more help let me know I will clear it

Comment: canvasfabric.getObjects('i-text') which will return all IText objects, if you want to use do a type check in all iteration`canvasfabric.forEachObject(function(obj,i){if(obj.type=='i-text') console.log(obj.text)})`

Comment: @Durga same issue it is giving blank space

Comment: if it is possible for you to create small fiddle/snippet please do.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13puats6/1/) you are making a group, thats why you are not getting text value. check the fiddle

Comment: @Durga thank you so much finally I got what I wanted....

Comment: @Durga can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611007/how-to-remove-previous-frames-rectangle-from-canvas/